# Java kills daemon threads in applet reloads

Tags: java, applet, daemon

I know that all daemon threads are supposed to be killed when no other non-daemon thread is alive.
I am developping applet which gets data from static objects. Those static objects are downloading some data from remote server in daemon thread. Several applets can access the same data so there is no sense in running thread for every applet.
Problem is when I reload page. Applets are reloading and they registers in those static objects and everything would be just fine except that then JVM kills daemon threads.

Maybe I explain step by step:

1. Applet is loading and it registers in static object which provides data.
2. Static object starts daemon thread.
3. Page reload.
4. Applet is beeing unloaded (stop() and destroy() are called)
5. New applet instance is beeing created and it registers in static object.
6. JVM throws ThreadDeath in daemon thread and communication stops.

In my mind, step 6 should be after 4 and before 5.
Am I missing something?

The workaround I developed is to sleep some time before registering in static object to let JVM kill daemons and then daemon is automaticaly created but it is only a workaround. Is there a some better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you terminate the daemon thread in `stop()` or `destroy()` to make things more clear.

Comment: becouse there can be another applets instance or other object waiting for data from server. Problem is in moment when daemon is killed by JVM not why.

Answer (score 0):

I would not encourage sharing background threads between applets, but if you insist, well you can do the following:

You can catch ThreadDeath by overriding Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler to be sure not to miss it.
You can then relaunch a new deamon thread from that handler to replace the killed one.

You should ensure you don't use synchronized on shared members in background threads, since your thread can be stopped while in the middle of a synchronized block, as documented by Thread.stop (the Java plugin uses Thread.stop to kill your threads).

Note that if you have at least 2 applets opened in 2 different tabs, reloading one does not make the JVM kill your thread.
The daemon flag does not seem to have any effect in applet environment.